# Validating multiple inputs with a shorter code in PHP

Tags: php, validation, optimization

The below code shows the process of validating 2 input fields. At the end i return in Json the Boolean result of each input.

Imagine i will do the following 20 more times, the code is large. How can an i perform the same procedure with shorter code?

```
$res =false;
$res2 = false;
    if(isset($_POST['Ans1'])) //if user checked ans1 radio
        {
          if($_POST['Ans1'] == "x divides y") #correct answer
          {
                $res = true;
          }
          else{#wrong answer
              $res = false;
          }
        }
        else{ #not checked
            $res = false;  
        }


        if(isset($_POST['Ans2'])) //if user checked ans2 radio
        {
          if($_POST['Ans2'] == "x greater than y") #correct answer
          {
                $res2 = true;
          }
          else{#wrong answer
              $res2 = false;
          }
        }
        else{ #not checked
            $res2 = false;
        }

        echo json_encode(['an1'=>$res,'an2'=>$res2]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function to check answer like this one:

```
function checkAnswer($key, $val) {
    $mapping = [
        'Ans1' => 'x divides y',
        'Ans2' => 'x greater than y'
    ];

    return $mapping[$key] == $val;
}
```

You will need a mapping of answers. You can then loop the POST array to check the answers; if POST only has answers.

```
$result = [];
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $res = checkAnswer($key, $val);
    $result[$key] = $res;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: interesting can you make some validation to show how your code works?

Comment: Not tested, but should give you the basic idea. (Updated answer)

Comment: put a `;` after `$result = []` Your code works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, you keep switching between Javascript and PHP and this is what happens. ;) Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all else as already define as false

```
$res =false;
$res2 = false;
if(isset($_POST['Ans1']) && $_POST['Ans1'] == "x divides y") //isset and value check 
{
    $res = true;
}

if(isset($_POST['Ans2']) && $_POST['Ans2'] == "x greater than y") //isset and value check
{
 $res2 = true;
}
echo json_encode(['an1'=>$res,'an2'=>$res2]);
```

Comment: If you use something like this, you will need to define 20 $res variables as false at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the $_POST and use an array with correct answers to compare against.

The return is an array with true/false on each answer.

```
$correct = ["x divides y", "x greater than y"]; // and so on...
$i=0;
foreach($_POST as $key => $Ans){
    if(isset($Ans)){ //if user checked radio
        if($Ans == $correct[$i]){ #correct answer
            $res[$key] = true;
        }else{ #wrong answer
            $res[$key] = false;
        }
    }else{ #not checked
        $res[$key] = false;  
    }
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($res); // example: Ans1 : true, Ans2 : false
```

If your `$_POST` has other values you can use preg_grep to filter only the answers.

```
$POST = preg_grep("/Ans\d+/", $_POST);
```

And then loop $POST instead.

Comment: How can i return the result of each boolean ? I used `echo json_encode(['an1'=>$res[0],'an2'=>$res[1]]); `

Comment: Does it have to be `an1` and not as your post value `Ans1`?

Comment: It doesn't matter it is an example